# retrieving the duplicate SSN from the huge number of employess all of them

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have written this query for getting the employees with same SSN numbers. But this query is giving me the all the employess, can't figure out whats wrong with it.

```
SELECT a.empid, 
       a.NAME, 
       a.ssn 
FROM   p_data a 
WHERE  ssn IN (SELECT ssn 
               FROM   p_data b 
               WHERE  b.ssn = a.ssn 
               GROUP  BY ssn 
               HAVING ( a.ssn ) > 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want groups with more than one record(duplicates), so use

```
HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1);
```

instead of

```
HAVING ( a.ssn ) > 1);
```

Another approach which should be more efficient:

```
SELECT a.empid, 
       a.NAME, 
       a.ssn 
FROM   p_data a 
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM p_data a2
    WHERE  a.empid <> a2.empid
    AND    a.ssn = a2.ssn 
)
```

This also works if `SSN` is nullable. Then you just have to change the last line to:

```
AND COALESCE(a.ssn, '') = COALESCE(a2.ssn, '')
```

Comment: The second one does work, but the issue with the first one is that is shows the missing parameter error, you can check it out in here-

Comment: select a.emplid, a.First_name, a.SSN from Ps_personal_data a
where SSN in (select SSN from ps_personal_data b where b.SSN = a.SSN Group by SSN having (*)>1);

Comment: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 21

Comment: It's not `having (*)>1` but `having count(*)>1` as i've shown in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, my senior was damn happy, as the query with Exists keyword is having optimum logic....